# Why does PHP deletes the content of the file on input?

Tags: php

I have one file: `configuration.txt`.

This file gets read by PHP, then wrote by the same PHP, while a C++ program reads the content of the same file at a regular interval.

PHP:

```
$closeFlag = false;
$arrayInputs = new SplFixedArray(3);
$arrayInputs[0] = "URL not entered";
$arrayInputs[1] = "3";
$arrayInputs[2] = "50";
$configFilePath = "/var/www/html/configuration.txt";
$currentSettingsFile = fopen($configFilePath, "r");

if(flock($currentSettingsFile, LOCK_SH)) {
    $arrayInputs = explode(PHP_EOL, fread($currentSettingsFile, filesize($configFilePath)));
    flock($currentSettingsFile, LOCK_UN);
    $closeFlag = fclose($currentSettingsFile);
}

if(isset( $_POST['save_values'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['getURL'])) {
        $arrayInputs[0] = $_POST['getURL'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['getURR'])) {
        $arrayInputs[1] = $_POST['getURR'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['getBrightness'])) {
        $arrayInputs[2] = $_POST['getBrightness'];
    }
}

if(!$closeFlag) fclose($currentSettingsFile);
$currentSettingsFile = fopen($configFilePath, "w");

if(flock($currentSettingsFile, LOCK_SH)) {
    foreach ($arrayInputs as $key => $value) {
        if($value != '')
            fwrite($currentSettingsFile,$value.PHP_EOL);
    }
    flock($currentSettingsFile, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($currentSettingsFile);
}
?>
```

C++

```
char configFilePath[]="/var/www/html/configuration.txt";
std::fstream configFile;

configFile.open(configFilePath, std::fstream::in);
if(configFile.is_open()){
// do stuff
} else {
      std::cout<<"Error ! Could not open Configuration file to read"<<std::endl;
    }
```

The c++ returned no error so far. It can open the file. And php will return `Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0` because the file is empty.

I believe that PHP is deleting the file's content.

Comment: Why aren't you locking the file in C++? Also, you need to lock the file BEFORE you open it, not after. The order is: Lock the file, open it, close it, unlock it. You need to have EVERY program perform the same locking routine or you will have a race condition.

Comment: you open the file with PHP using the `w` flag : 'w'  Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and __truncate the file to zero length__. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: @kainaw because it is very hard to lock files in C++. How would you lock `std::fstream configFile;` ?

Comment: @jibsteroos Did you see what comes after opening the file in `w` mode ? It comes a code that wrties to file.

Comment: @bleah1 You lock a "lock" file to indicate that the main file is locked. That is standard practice.

Comment: @kainaw I don't understand what you are trying to say with `You lock a "lock" file to indicate that the main file is locked.`. Can you please speak in examples ?

Comment: did you try to add `b` in your open? like : `$currentSettingsFile = fopen($configFilePath, "rb");` - or to check if the file can be found? `if (FALSE === $currentSettingsFile) {
    exit("Failed to open stream to URL");
}`

Comment: @kainaw Also, if you know how to lock a file in C++ but also keep the functionality of `std::fstream` please enlighten me. Because in C++ `flock()` needs two `int` : `int flock(int fd, int operation);`

Comment: @bleah1 If my file is "mystuff.txt", I don't pass "mystuff.txt" as my lock file. I create a lock file like "mystuff.lock". I lock that file. Then, when it is locked, I know I can use mystuff.txt in PHP or as a stream. You don't lock the actual file itself. You lock a lock file associated with the file.

Comment: @kainaw That just pushed my project a week back.

Comment: @bleah1 Fopen the lock file to get a handle and use that in flock. If it succeeds, you can open the main file as a stream without problem.

Comment: @bleah conditionally writes to a file you mean :-)

Comment: @jibsteroos Yes. Maybe that's where it fails. It opens the file in `w` mode, truncate it, but then it can't get the lock so it never writes to it.

Comment: @kainaw Can you please write an example of what you are talking about should look like ? Because I have no clue of where to start at.

Comment: @kainaw I've tried locking the file before opening it, but isn't it impossible ? `flock`needs a file as a parameter. If I don't open a file, where do I get the parameter for `flock` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When locking a file in PHP, you lock a LOCK file, not the main file. Example:

```
$myfile = 'myfile.txt';
$lockfile = 'myfile.lock';
$lock = fopen($lockfile,'a');
if(flock($lock, LOCK_EX)) // The lock file is locked in exclusive mode - so I can write to it.
{
  $fp = fopen($myfile,'w');
  fputs($fp, "I am writing safely!");
  fclose($fp);
  flock($lock, LOCK_UN); // Always unlock it!
}
fclose($lock);
```

You work similarly in C++ because PHP is not locking the actual file. It is locking a lock file. The exact syntax depends heavily on your version of C/C++ and the operating system. So, I will use minimal syntax.

```
int lock=fopen(lockfile, "r+");
if(flock(fileno(lock), LOCK_EX))
{
  //Locked. You can open a stream to ANOTHER file and play with it.
  flock(fileno(lock), LOCK_UN));
}
fclose(lock);
```

Comment: Do I need a lock file even if I read the file ? For this particular file, only PHP writes in it, C++ only reads from it.

Comment: If you want to lock, you need a lock file. If you are reading, you lock with LOCK_SH. If you are editing, you lock with LOCK_EX.

Comment: Also, who is `lockfile` in C++ ?

Comment: A variable. If you are stuck on using "fopen", do not try to use locks. Pass this project to someone else.

Comment: I can't pass it to someone else, because there isn't someone else. It's only me. And I need to learn how to do this stuff.

Comment: That is what college is for. You wouldn't get through my C++ or operating sytems course without learning to work with files.

Comment: I don't really understand why or how this works. You are making an empty file, name it whatever you want, give it `lock` extension and use it as a handler. You are reading/writing the original file only if this `file.lock` is available for C++ or PHP, respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199958/discussion-between-bleah1-and-kainaw).